# Demonstrate that if $ {\sqrt{a}} + {\sqrt{b}}\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $ {\sqrt{a}}\in\mathbb{Q}$ and ${\sqrt{b}}\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$

if $$ {\sqrt{a}} + {\sqrt{b}}\in\mathbb{Q}$$

demonstrates: $$ {\sqrt{a}}\in\mathbb{Q}$$
              $${\sqrt{b}}\in\mathbb{Q}$$ 
I try to solve it with the property:

If x, y $\in\mathbb{Q}$ then x + y $\in\mathbb{Q}$ and xy $\in\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: If $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=r$, then $\sqrt{a} = \dfrac{r^2+a-b}{2r}$.

Answer (score 10):

*Hint:* $\sqrt a-\sqrt b=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}$ and $\sqrt a=\frac{(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)+(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)}2$.

Answer (score 4):

$$
{\sqrt{a}} + {\sqrt{b}}\in\mathbb{Q} \implies {\sqrt{ab}} \in\mathbb{Q} \implies {\sqrt{ab}} + b={\sqrt{b}}({\sqrt{a}} + {\sqrt{b}})\in\mathbb{Q} \implies {\sqrt{b}}\in\mathbb{Q} 
$$