# Proof about square roots of rational numbers being rational/irrational

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, field-theory, extension-field

$$ a,b \in  \mathbb{Q} $$
$$ \sqrt{a} \notin \mathbb{Q}  ~\text{and}~ \sqrt{b} \notin \mathbb{Q} \implies \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} \notin \mathbb{Q}    $$

I'm not really sure on how to solve this, however, I know it's true, it's an implication of a theorem,  how can I prove this directly?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/511392/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2542943/42969.

Comment: You should try it once using field extension.